# Firebase Email Link Authentication Does Not Open iOS App Store

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication

When a company admin adds a user account in our web app we want to send that user an authentication link that they can use to download the app and be automatically logged in (after confirming their email).

Right now if we send them an authentication link and the app is not installed it will open the web app in Safari instead of the iOS app store.

If the app is already installed it works correctly and opens the app so it is definitely set up correctly. Also if I generate a (non-authentication) dynamic link from the Firebase console it works correctly and opens the iOS app store if the app is not installed.

The way we send the email is:

```
await auth().sendSignInLinkToEmail(this.email, {
  url: "https://app.example.com",
  handleCodeInApp: true,
  iOS: {
    bundleId: "com.example.Example",
  },
  android: {
    packageName: "com.example.Example",
    installApp: true,
  },
  dynamicLinkDomain: "example.page.link",
});
```